# Program crashes when deleting dynamic array C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I wrote a program that dynamically allocates memory for an array of structure. It seems to work fine but when ever I try to delete the array the computer makes a "bong" noise and the program stops responding. It doesn't throw an error or anything, it just stops. I have tried `delete` and `delete[]` with the same result. I've tried moving the location of delete and found that I can delete it right after its created, but not after its been passed to any functions. Can anyone tell me why I can't delete memory?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::setw;
using std::left;
using std::fixed;
using std::setprecision;

//structure of an employee
struct Employee
{
    char first_name[32];
    char last_name[32];
    char SSN[11];
    float wage;
    int hours;
    char status;
};

void ReadData(Employee work_force[]);
void PrintData(Employee work_force[], int number_entries);
float CalculateStarightPay(Employee worker);
float CalculateOvertimePay(Employee worker);
int FindNumberEntries();

const int SPACING = 15;                             //spacing used in formating
const char dataFile[] = "EmployeeData.txt";         //file to read data from
const int union_dues = 5;                           //amount deducted from pay for the union

int main()
{
    int number_entries = FindNumberEntries();
    //array of employees
    Employee * work_force = new Employee[number_entries];

    //read in data
    ReadData(work_force);

    //prints the data
    PrintData(work_force, number_entries);

    //clean up memory
    delete[] work_force;

    return 0;
}

//finds the number of entries in the file
int FindNumberEntries()
{
    int counter = 0;
    //worker to read through file entries
    Employee worker_temp;

    ifstream input;

    input.open(dataFile);

    if (input.is_open())
    {
        while (!input.eof())
        {
            input >>
                worker_temp.first_name >>
                worker_temp.last_name >>
                worker_temp.SSN >>
                worker_temp.wage >>
                worker_temp.hours >>
                worker_temp.status;

            cin.clear();

            counter++;
        }

        input.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened!" << endl;
    }

        return counter - 1;
}

//reads employee data from file
void ReadData(Employee work_force[])
{
    ifstream input;

    input.open(dataFile);

    //reads in entries
    if (input.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; !input.eof(); i++)
        {
            //reads in employee data
            input >>
                work_force[i].first_name >>
                work_force[i].last_name >>
                work_force[i].SSN >>
                work_force[i].wage >>
                work_force[i].hours >>
                work_force[i].status;

            cin.clear();
        }

        input.close();
    }
    else
    {
        //error that file could not open
        cout << "File could not be opened!" << endl;
    }

}

//calculates straight pay
float CalculateStarightPay(Employee worker)
{
    //determines of worker is fulltime or not
    if (worker.status == 'F')
    {
        if (worker.hours > 40)
        {
            return ((worker.wage * 40) - 5);
        }
        else
        {
            return (worker.wage * worker.hours) - union_dues;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (worker.hours > 40)
        {
            return (worker.wage * 40);
        }
        else
        {
            return worker.wage * worker.hours;
        }
    }
}

//calculate overtime pay
float CalculateOvertimePay(Employee worker)
{
    //deermines if there are any overtime hours
    if (worker.hours <= 40)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //calculates overtime pay
        return ((worker.hours - 40) * (worker.wage * 1.5));
    }
}

//prints employee data in a well formated manner
void PrintData(Employee work_force[], int number_entries)
{
    delete work_force;
    float straight_pay = 0.0F;
    float Overtime_pay = 0.0F;
    char name[32] = { '\0' };

    //print headers
    cout << left <<
        setw(SPACING) << "Name" <<
        setw(SPACING) << "SSN" <<
        setw(SPACING) << "Hourly Wage" <<
        setw(SPACING) << "Hours Worked" <<
        setw(SPACING) << "Straight Pay" <<
        setw(SPACING) << "Overtime Pay" << 
        setw(SPACING) << "Status" << 
        setw(SPACING) << "Net Pay" << endl;

    //prints data for each EMPLOYEE
    for (int i = 0; i < number_entries; i++)
    {
        straight_pay = CalculateStarightPay(work_force[i]);
        Overtime_pay = CalculateOvertimePay(work_force[i]);
        //adds a space after first name
        work_force[i].first_name[strlen(work_force[i].first_name) + 1] = '\0';
        work_force[i].first_name[strlen(work_force[i].first_name)] = ' ';
        //puts last name and first name together
        strcpy(name, strcat(work_force[i].first_name, work_force[i].last_name));

        //prints out all the data in a nic eformat
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) <<
            setw(SPACING ) << name <<
            setw(SPACING) << work_force[i].SSN << '$' <<
            setw(SPACING) << work_force[i].wage <<
            setw(SPACING) << work_force[i].hours << '$' <<
            setw(SPACING) << straight_pay << '$' <<
            setw(SPACING) << Overtime_pay <<
            setw(SPACING) << work_force[i].status << '$' <<
            setw(SPACING) << (straight_pay + Overtime_pay) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do it wrong `while (!input.eof())` (`cin.clear();` is useless)

Comment: But... why would you `delete` something in a function named `PrintData`??? You're even doing `work_force[i]` after that.

Comment: Is this a joke/spam ? `delete work_force;`in `PrintData` ! No one would do that by mistake....

Comment: Please, use `std::string` inside your `Employee` structure.  The `std::string` is a safer and easier to use data structure than C-Style character arrays.

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#, so why are you dynamically allocating memory instead of using `std::vector`?

Comment: When you used the debugger, and executed each statement one at a time, which statement was the last one executed before the crash?

Comment: You input loop has the wrong terminating condition.  Search Stackoverflow for "c++ eof bad".

Comment: You are clearing the status of `cin` while reading from an input *file*.  Is there a reason for clearing the status of `cin` when you don't use it in the loop?

Comment: If you used `std::vector`, you could find the number of employees by using `std::vector::size()`, instead of having to read the file again.  If you must use an array, then use a variable that indicates the number of employee records that were read.  This concept eliminates the need to read the file again.  P.S. don't copy and paste code, refactor the common code into a new function.

Comment: I recommend overloading `operator>>` (formatted input) and `operator<<` (formatted output) in your `Employee` class.  This reduces the coupling between functions and your `Employee` class as well as increasing the level of encapsulation and data hiding. (Or you could make input and output methods for your `Employee` class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't `delete work_force;` at the top of `PrintData`.
2. Use `std::string`s for your names and SSN.  (Fixed length strings are a usability accident waiting to happen).
3. Use a `std::vector<Employee>`.  The important thing is that this means you no longer have to use `new` (which is something you should always try and avoid).  It also means that you only have to read the file once - you just read the entry, and then push it onto the vector with `push_back`.
4. When reading from an input stream, you need to try to read *and then test the stream* to see if you have hit eof.  So the read function would look like:

   ```
       while (input >>
            worker_temp.first_name >>
            worker_temp.last_name >>
            worker_temp.SSN >>
            worker_temp.wage >>
            worker_temp.hours >>
            worker_temp.status)
       {
            workforce.push_back(worker_temp);
       }
   ```